# Binary trees, returning the next node in a preorder traversal

Tags: java, binary-tree, preorder

I have an assignment and I need some help with a method.

So I have a tree like this:

```
                A
              /   \
             B     C
           /   \ /   \
          D    E F     G
        /   \
       H      I
     /   \
   J       K
```

and my method is:

```
public BinaryTree preorderNext(BinaryTree t, BinaryTree v, BinaryTree prev) {       

    prev = t;

    if(t.getLeft() != null) {
        preorderNext(t.getLeft(), v, prev);
    }

    if(t.getRight() != null) {
        preorderNext(t.getRight(), v, prev);
    }


    if(prev == v) {
        return t;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The lecturer had given a simple implementation of the tree. The class is called BinaryTree and if you want to make a node link to it then you specify what the right and left child BinaryTree node are.

A node has two links (one to the left and the other to the right child) and there is no link to the head.

So with the current method I am able to successful do a preorder traversal, I tested by writing the print statements of what the element stored at the node is.

But when I run the tests, it tells me that the next preorder node from A is B, and the next preorder node from K throws a null exception but it should be I?

Any ideas of where I am going wrong? The variable prev should hold a reference to the last node visited so if it equals to node v (which is the node I specify, to return the node after v), shouldn't I get the next node?

Comment: Can you modify the function signature? It is much easier to deal with the `root` than with `t`, `v` and `prev`. This is because every child of the tree is also a tree itself.

Comment: What do you mean? t is the root of the tree which i can pass in.

Comment: You should hold a recursive approach rather than pass previously visited information to the method again; this information is already within the stack. I will post an answer to explain my approach for the preorder traversal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an implementation of how a `preorder traversal` is done recursively.

```
public void preOrderTraversal(BinaryTree root){
    if(root == null) return;

    System.out.println(root);
    preOrderTraversal(root.getLeft());
    preOrderTraversal(root.getRight());
}
```

Notes:

1. I am not sure of your approach; why are you returning a node? In any case, when the `root` is null with that approach you can return an "`emptyNode`" and deal with it by an if statement.
2. As you can see I am only dealing with the `root`, with any level the `root` changes. Try to visualize this with a run-through and you will understand this concept.
3. You are missing a check for null nodes at the beginning (especially for `t`).

You can continue to adapt your results to this.

A final note is for the run-time complexity of this approach, I'd highly recommend understanding run-time complexities for recursive functions. It will help you **a lot** in the future. Check [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) for recurrence relations.

Comment: I can see what you are trying to do.
I am returning a node because to get the next node of a node, so the next node of K in a pre order traversal is I..
 
You said in a comment of my previous post that my nodes will be held in a stack... so how can I obtain J when i vist it and get the next node after J?

Comment: Next node of `K` will be `I` with the control flow of the recursion. What I mean is, after you process `K` (print it out, do some operation on it etc.) the method will return to the previous call and will have the current `root` as `I` (in your case the `t` will be `I` I believe). These will be handled by the stack automatically, you need not worry about that. Please look into Stack and how it is used with recursion and you will understand this.

Comment: I understand how the stack works with recursive calls.


Lets say I am just going to traverse the left side of the tree.

- First check if A has a left, it does so recursive call on it
- then check if b has a left, it does so recursive call on it
- then check D has a left, it does so recursive call on it
- then check H has a left, it does so recursive call on it

Comment: - then check J has a left, it does not so return from the recursive call
- now check if H has a right, it does and now we can return from that recursive call
- now check if D has a right, it does
- now we can if I has a left, it does not, and check if it has a right - it does not
- then we check if B has a right, it does.


I dont see how I am able to go from K to I...

My logic is correct here yes?

Comment: @miniJavaLearner I have been extremely busy and couldn't respond quickly, sorry about that. If you create a chat room here, we can discuss about this problem (I don't want to keep posting a lot of comments, thanks).

Comment: No problem, I managed to solve it now. Thanks a lot for your explanation

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if doing that task recursively is that easy.

Solving the task the iterative way using a stack could be a much better approach:

```
public BinaryTree preOrderNext(BinaryTree toSearch) {

    Stack<BinaryTree> openList = new Stack<BinaryTree>();

    openList.push(root);

    while (openList.empty() == false) {
        BinaryTree curr = openList.pop();

        if (curr.getRight() != null)
            openList.push(curr.getRight());

        if (curr.getLeft() != null)
            openList.push(curr.getLeft());

        if (curr.equals(toSearch) && openList.empty() == false){
            return openList.pop();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method is not tested, but should be working.

Comment: You should not use identity operator `==`, rather `equals()` within your last `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I provide an answer that runs in `O(h)` running time.

```
class Node {
    public int key;
    public Node l;
    public Node r;
    public Node p;

    public Node(int key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.l = null;
        this.r = null;
        this.p = null;
    }
}

public Node preorderNext(Node v) {
    if (v.l != null) {
        return v.l;
    } else if (v.r != null) {
        return v.r;
    } else {
        while (v.p != null) {
            if (v == v.p.l) {
                if (v.p.r != null) {
                    return v.p.r;
                } else {
                    v = v.p;
                }
            } else {
                if (v.p.p == null) {
                    return null;
                } else if (v.p == v.p.p.l) {
                    if (v.p.p.r != null) {
                        return v.p.p.r;
                    } else {
                        v = v.p;
                    }
                } else {
                    v = v.p;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this return a different node, the correct node, on each call for a pre-order traversal?  Thats actually pretty amazing.